# is all the signal handlers invoked by kernel when a signal was pended?

Tags: linux, signals, sigbus

I have three different process. They all have their own signal handlers for a signal. All handlers has its own logs. I create artificially signal with another process. I saw only one handler's log in the console. I expected to see all the logs. Is the behaviour correct?

Comment: Did you send the signal to all three processes?

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).